# What is a contiguous shuffle partition in Spark?

Tags: apache-spark

I am reading this spark guide about adaptive query execution:

https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.3.0/sql-performance-tuning.html#coalescing-post-shuffle-partitions

And they talk about `contiguous shuffle partitions`. What is a `contiguous shuffle partition`?

Can someone give an example of a `non-contiguous shuffle partition`? What is the difference between `contiguous` and `non-contiguous shuffle partitions`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The term "contiguous shuffle partition" in the context of Spark's Adaptive Query Execution (AQE) refers to a group of shuffle partitions that are processed together as a single task.

Normally, each shuffle partition in Spark corresponds to a separate task. However, with AQE enabled, Spark can coalesce small shuffle partitions at runtime into fewer, larger tasks to avoid the overhead of scheduling and processing many small tasks. This coalescing of partitions is done in a "contiguous" manner, meaning that only shuffle partitions that are adjacent to each other (i.e., have consecutive partition IDs) can be coalesced together.

So, when the Spark guide talks about "contiguous shuffle partitions", it's referring to these groups of shuffle partitions that have been coalesced together into a single task by AQE.

As for a "non-contiguous shuffle partition", I believe this would refer to a scenario where shuffle partitions are not coalesced together, either because AQE is not enabled or because the shuffle partitions are not small enough to be coalesced. In this case, each shuffle partition would correspond to a separate task, as is the norm without AQE.